# MySQL, SELECT * FROM t WHERE c={The most duplicated entry}

Tags: mysql

Pretty much as the title says, that was the simplest way I could explain it. To elaborate...

I first need to find the value of column c that has been duplicated the most times (mostDuplicated), and then `SELECT * FROM t WHERE c=mostDuplicated`

To go on about it further...

Here's my data:

```
SELECT * FROM t

a, b, c
-  -  -
1, 1, 1
2, 2, 1
3, 3, 1
4, 4, 2
5, 5, 3
```

So ignore the values in columns a & b completely, just concentrate on column c. I need to find the most duplicated value in column c (which is 1), and then SELECT only these records WHERE c=1. I want to do this in a single query if possible.

Comment: What if there were tied "most duplicate" values of `c`?

Comment: @MartinSmith: Good question, then I suppose it doesn't matter which one is selected, BUT it still does only have to be one value in the where clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do a "group by" query to count the number of unique values of `c`, order it descending and select only the top row. Then use the output as a subquery to select rows with that particular value of `c`:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE c = (SELECT c FROM t GROUP BY c ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Best answer, with fewest sub-queries. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

`SELECT c FROM t GROUP BY c ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: Thanks, but this will only select 1 row, I want to know the values of columns a & b where c=1. This will only select 1 row

Comment: Then `SELECT * FROM t WHERE c = (SELECT c FROM t GROUP BY c ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1)` and please specify that in your question next time :)

Comment: It is specified in the question. The other 2 answerers noticed it.

Comment: stick with the solution from this answer, just remove select c with select *, don't use the one with the subquery

Comment: @Octopus-Paul good point. I wrote that out as a db-agnostic query out of habit.

Comment: @Octopus-Paul: No this first one won't work, even by replacing with *. It groups by column c, and also has a limit on it. So it will always return 1 row, and not all of them where c=1. If I were to remove the limit and the group then all I'm left with is an ordered table, but still has the non-applicable rows. My point is that the query won't work because it has no WHERE clause in it.

Answer (score 1):

Well it will be, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE c = 
               (SELECT c FROM 
                    (SELECT c, count(c) as co 
                            FROM t ORDER BY co DESC LIMIT 1))
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, it's a bit convoluted:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    t
WHERE
(
    c IN
    (
        SELECT c
        FROM (
                SELECT
                    c,
                    COUNT(c) as freq
                FROM
                    t
                GROUP BY
                    c
                ORDER BY
                    freq DESC,
                    c ASC
                LIMIT 1
            ) AS t2
    )
)
```

Basically, it's going this:
1. determine how often each value of C is repeated
2. select the value of the MAXimum repeats
3. use that value to determine what value of C to use when select * from the entire table.